# count columns from sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to count the number of rows selected from a table by using the count() function. But it always returns either a '2' for every query with a row/rows selected or a '1' for every query with no row selected.

```
 $sql_usb="select item_name from req_item where item_name='USB Dongle'";
 $result_usb=mysql_query($sql_usb);
 $row_usb=mysql_fetch_array($result_usb);

 $sql_router="select item_name from req_item where item_name='Access Point/Router'";
 $result_router=mysql_query($sql_router);
 $row_router=mysql_fetch_array($result_router);

 $sql_laptop="select item_name from req_item where item_name='Laptop'";
 $result_laptop=mysql_query($sql_laptop);
 $row_laptop=mysql_fetch_array($result_laptop);

 $usb_inv=count($row_usb);
 $router_inv=count($row_router);
 $laptop_inv=count($row_laptop);


 $total_inv=$usb_inv+$router_inv+$laptop_inv;
```

I've also tried adding isset() (i.e. `$usb_inv=count(isset($row_usb));`)
and mysql_num_rows() (i.e. `$usb_inv=mysql_num_rows($row_usb));`)

both give a result of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use count in you mysql query like this

```
$SelectQuery = 'select Count(item_name) as [TotalUSB] from req_item where item_name='USB Dongle'
```

Then you can get the result by

```
$result = mysql_query($SelectQuery);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$USBCount = $row['TotalUSB'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

`SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ....`

Check the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/counting-rows.html).

If you only need the total, then only 1 sql will be enough.

```
// please add error handing yourself.
$sql = "select count(*) from req_item where item_name
        where item_name in('USB Dongle', 'Access Point/Router', 'Laptop')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$total = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have used mysql_num_rows on result set.

like this.

```
$usb_inv=mysql_num_rows($result_usb);
$router_inv=mysql_num_rows($result_router);
$laptop_inv=mysql_num_rows($result_laptop);
```

this will give you proper output.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$usb_inv = mysql_num_rows($result_usb);
```

instead of

```
$usb_inv=count($row_usb);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array is returning something like

```
$row[0] = ...;
$row[item_name] = ...;
```

If you are using count of an array, it will always return a two,
because it return an array with both index and associate key.

> array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
>
> mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

Despite the wrong usage of mysql_fetch_array,
you probably should just use a single query

```
$sql ="select item_name from req_item 
       where item_name in('USB Dongle', 'Access Point/Router', 'Laptop')";
```

after that,

```
$count = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  // do something else ...

  // to get count for each item name
  $count[$row["item_name"]]++;
}
```

Comment: If the op only need the total count, it's unnecessary to do this.

Comment: of course, but who know what OP actually need? you can see him even doing `$row_laptop = ...`

Comment: Yep, The OP has already check the right answer, obviously there is no something else :)